# model save is not working in the yii and it is not redirecting to view page

Tags: php, yii

I am using following code in my controller. Have a look into that and let me know about the issue.

```
$model = new Model;

if (isset($_POST['Model'])) {  
    if ($model->save) {
        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not assigning the POST data to the model? Maybe try `$model->attributes = $POST['Model'];`

Comment: `save` it is method. And you must validate model. like this: `if ($model->validate()) { $model->save(); } else { ... }`. Validate() working before save() automatically. It means model can have errors and not save record to db.

Answer (score 0):

I can assume, you can try following change:

```
$model= new Model();
if(isset($_POST['Model'])){
    $model->attributes = $POST['Model']
    if($model->save)
        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$model= new Model();

if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)
{
    $model->attributes = $_POST['Model']

    if($model->save)
        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code.
First you are not setting the values of the model.
Second. save is a function, not a variable

```
$model = new Model;

if (isset($_POST['Model'])) {
    // Fix 1. Save the details from the form to your model
    $model->setAttributes = $_POST['Model'];
    // Fix 2. Save is a function. Notice the ()
    if ($model->save()) {
        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }
}
```